# How to loop get make output in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure to return `title` of some products from the table name called `Products`. `Products` table contains the column named `title`. On my sql server its already enabled full-text index for table `Product` and column called `title`. Bellow the naked query is given-

```
SELECT TOP 10000 KEY_TBL.[KEY] FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Products, Title, 'pot') AS KEY_TBL ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

Note: `pot` is the keyword and i am using Microsoft sql server

So basically it will return those product id which has marching keyword `pot` on its title. And if i run above query now i result looks like bellow-

https://ibb.co/XJ9GHtC

Now i have inserted this query into stored procedure like bellow. But problem is- since my query only returns id of products not its title so i need to loop though these product ids then return those product title as output on this stored procedure. But query bellow is not working since i am missing loop part of it. Anyone can give me hints how can i achieve this? So output will return Product title not just its key id?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductsByKeyword] 
    @Keyword nvarchar(255) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ItemsTable TABLE(
    title nvarchar(250)
    )


    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Query='SELECT TOP 10000 KEY_TBL.[KEY] FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Products, Title, @Keyword) AS KEY_TBL ORDER BY RANK DESC'





SELECT * FROM @ItemsTable           

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END;
```

Comment: That SP doesn't make sense. What is `@Query`for? The SQL is never executed, and why does it need to be executed as a dynamic statement (if it was), when there's nothing dynamic about it. Are we missing some key parts of your statement here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chances are you don't need a loop, depending on how you want your output to be consumed.

If you simply execute the SQL code directly inside the procedure without putting it into a variable or loop then the results will be returned directly from the stored procedure as a result set. This would be the same kind of result as if you ran the SQL inside a query window in SSMS.

If you want to return the results in another format, plain text, XML, JSON or something else like CSV then you have other choices.
Give us a little more information on how you want to consume the results and we can give more help.